# how to query a mongodb using a field which is inside an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a db object like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectID("55c247f94b0c25e5d90d0f39"),
   "districts": [
    {
        "district": "Bangalore Urban",
        "stateID": 2,
        "districtID": 1
    },
    {
        "district": "Tumkur",
        "stateID": 2,
        "districtID": 2
    }
]
}
```

and i have stateID with me, what mongoose query should i write to get all objects from the array `districts` having the stateID 2

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection). Various answers mentioning `.aggregate()` which is suitable for multiple matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an `aggregate` query. Your Mongo query will look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: 'districts'
}, {
    $match: {
        'stateID': 2
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        'districts': {
        $push: '$districts'
        }
    }
}]);
```

`$unwind` creates a record from each item inside an array.

`$match` is your query for finding items of your stateID

`$group` groups all your results in a custom key **districts**.

Comment: this is returning me the full db object, no selection is happening

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood your question. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @syedfaizan Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks bro , you saved my day, forgot to comment yesterday, sorry